# JS Regex to remove everything outside certain html tags (including tags)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xml-parsing

I have a SOAP output that need to parse via JS REGEX, (i know there is plenty of js libraries that will do the job, and i know that regex is not the best thing to parse html / xml, but in this case, it has to be done via regex)...

This is the format...

```
*huge header*
<NewDataSet>
*content*
</NewDataSet>
*rest of footer*
```

i need ro remove everything that is outside the `<NewDataSet>` and `</NewDataSet>` (including them, and leaving the tags in the `*content*` area, untouched...

I've been trying to make this work, but it seems to be harder than i expected... Please, somebody help

Comment: Why do you have to use regex? There must be a better solution.

Comment: [**NEVER NEVER NEVER PARSE XML/HTML WITH REGEX**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1249581).

Comment: I have a lot of html tags between those `<NewDataSet>` tags. `*content*`, is just a representation to a ton of html tags. But the `<NewDataSet>` and `</NewDataSet>`, are unique in the whole string

Comment: @VisioN when i asked my question, i have let explicit that i am aware that regex must not be used to parse HTML / XML.

Comment: @ghaschel ... yeah, and that's why you have decided to use it. Listen to Bergi: there *must be* a better solution.

Comment: If adding a library to a phonegap project to parse one single soap call, still better than doing this via regex, there is another option. Please Suggest me a good JS Library then... I just want to remove the header and footer, and use the html content that is inside those tags. Inside those tags is a ready-to-use html table. And all i want is use this table

Comment: @ghaschel Simply use DOM manipulation methods, like `createElement`, `getElementsByTagName`, `removeChild`, etc.

Comment: Look, here is an example of the output i get: http://pastebin.com/K6TkNzHF

I have to make an ajax call, and the text returned to me is this. I need to remove the header and footer in order to be able to use anything that resides inside the tags mentioned.

Comment: Basically, i need to transform this: http://pastebin.com/K6TkNzHF into this: http://pastebin.com/M6XHFCxx

Comment: That sounds like nearly the opposite of what you originally asked. You only want the `*content*`, but nothing else?

Comment: Damm, what a shame. Wrong word. Sorry for the big mess. Enlgihs is not my native language =x

Comment: Please respond by checking an answer or commenting to let us know if something worked for you or what problems you might still be having.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have javascript since you mention wanting to use javascript regex, why not use javascript like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/gHwd6/1/

```
var ds = document.getElementsByTagName('NewDataSet')[0];
var t = ds.getElementsByTagName('NewTable')[0];
ds.parentNode.replaceChild(t, ds);
```

This assumes there is only one `NewDataSet` tag and only one table within `NewDataSet` that you want to keep, named `NewTable`. It sounds like you will only have one of each, so you can just change the `NewTable` to whatever yours is called.

**Edit** after seeing your recent comments/edit that seem to change your requirement, try doing this to the data you are receiving:

```
myData = myData.getElementsByTagName('NewDataSet')[0].innerHTML;
```

Here is an example showing an application for it (view your console to see it is returning your desired output): http://jsfiddle.net/qmnNn/

Please respond by checking an answer or commenting to let us know if something worked for you or what problems you might still be having.